# One SQLite DB and two remote services: android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException:

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, cursor, android-service

I've a situation where I've two remote services accessing a SQLite DB. Each service is opening a separate connection to the db and are doing a insert/read/delete operations. The services are working fine except when they are stopped and re-started again.

I'm getting the following exception.

"android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here"

I double, tripple checked all my database open/close and cursor open/close statements. I'm still getting this error.

I can't seem to point my finger at the problem but it looks like it has something to do w/ the two services simultaneously accessing the DB w/ connections open at the same time.

Any suggestions / pointers?

I've separate open/close methods.

```
private void open() {
    m_database = m_helper.getWritableDatabase();
}

private void close() {
    if (m_database != null) {
        m_database.close();
    }
}
```

For every crud operation I explicitly open and close like this.

```
public long insert(int type, double latitude, double longitude, long timestamp, float speed, double altitude) {
    SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
    long status;
    open();
    insertStmt = m_database.compileStatement(INSERT);
    insertStmt.bindLong(1, type);
    insertStmt.bindDouble(2, latitude);
    insertStmt.bindDouble(3, longitude);
    insertStmt.bindLong(4, timestamp);
    insertStmt.bindDouble(5, speed);
    insertStmt.bindDouble(6, altitude);

    status = insertStmt.executeInsert();
    close();
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to close your DB itself (or helper) in `onDestroy` of your service?

Comment: No, I've not but I open and close for every DB (CRUD) operation. I'll give a shot anyways and update again.

Answer (score 1):

When using compiled statements, you will want to call the `close` method after your insert is complete.  These DatabaseObjectNotClosedException will happen a lot on android 2.2 if one forgets to do this.

```
public long insert(int type, double latitude, double longitude, long timestamp, float speed, double altitude) {
    SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
    long status;
    open();
    insertStmt = m_database.compileStatement(INSERT);
    insertStmt.bindLong(1, type);
    insertStmt.bindDouble(2, latitude);
    insertStmt.bindDouble(3, longitude);
    insertStmt.bindLong(4, timestamp);
    insertStmt.bindDouble(5, speed);
    insertStmt.bindDouble(6, altitude);

    status = insertStmt.executeInsert();
    // call close here
    insertStmt.close();
    close();
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that since your services are occuring simultaneously. One may finish before the other and  while the other is still open, the first finishing service may through the exception because the DB is still in use but not by it.

Comment: The services are continuously running in the background and don't stop until I explicitly call stopService() on them. The first service listens froms some events and inserts records into the DB and the second service reads the records, sends to a server and deletes the read records. The two services have their separate DB connections. I explicitly open/close for each insert / read / delete operation.